# Нет доступа к С:\Windows\ PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell

Хочу через PowerShell посчитать сколько занимают все файлы в папке Windows кроме .tmp файлов. Нет доступа хотя я администратор  и имею полный доступ....куда копать?

```
  $FolderSize = Get-ChildItem C:\Windows -Exclude *.tmp -Recurse  | measure -Property length -Sum;
        Write-Host $($FolderSize.Sum/1MB)
```

> Get-ChildItem : Отказано в доступе по пути "C:\Windows\CSC".
>       строка:1 знак:15
>       + $FolderSize = Get-ChildItem C:\Windows -Exclude *.tmp -Recurse  | measure -Prope ...
>       +               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>           + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (C:\Windows\CSC:String) [Get-ChildItem], UnauthorizedAccessException
>           + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

Answer (score 2):

Powershell нужно запустить с правами администратора. Именно *ПКМ / Запуск от имени администратора*

Comment: Задавайте вопросы в комментариях, а не в виде ответа

Comment: Думаете это не может быть решением проблемы пользователя? :) 
Но вообще спасибо, буду иметь в виду

Answer (score 0):

Так:

```
 $FolderSize = Get-ChildItem C:\Windows -Exclude *.tmp | measure -Property length -Sum
 Write-Host $($FolderSize.Sum/1MB)
```

Comment: Так неправильно считает. Подпапки не учитываются. Нужен -Recurse, а с ним нет доступа.

Comment: с рекурсией не получится, на это нету доступа по дефолту в папке C:\Windows